# transfer Database to another magento site to other magento site with different tempalte?

Tags: database

I'm tyring to rebuild new magento site from my previous one.
My New magento site will have different template and different version of magento site.

And I want to keep same catalog, order history, customer account history, categorioes.. all other database.    How can I transfer those information to another one safe?

I already know how to transfer all the database to another server but, i dont' know how to transfer database like old magento sample database.  so that I can start install new magento with old sample database.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach you can take if you already know how to change the DB between installations is to simply create a new theme and apply it.

If your current theme has some customizations regarding for example product/customer attributes you will have to port those customizations to your new theme, but it should not be complex.

You can also reuse the same DB/Server and just add a new theme to the installation.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply! But when i copy database to another mangento site and reinstalled magento and add new theme to it, some of the admin page or menu is not working. Like when I tried to add new account as customer, it give me error  "There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons."

Comment: If it solved your issue please mark is as accepted.